# React relay+router does not collapse queries of nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, relayjs, react-router-relay

I read on the [react-router-relay](https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay)  that:

> react-router-relay will automatically generate a combined Relay route
>   with all queries and parameters from the active React Router routes,
>   then pass down the query results to each of the route components. As
>   the queries are all gathered onto a single route, they'll all be
>   fetched at the same time, and the data for your entire page will load
>   and then render in one go.

But in my app I actually see two separate calls to `/graphql`. Here's my code:

```
<Route path="site_:siteId" component={AppSkeleton} queries={SiteAccountQueries}>
    <Route path="mySites" component={Sites} queries={SiteAccountQueries} />
</Route>
```

The first call fetches the data for `AppSkeleton`, and the second for `Sites`. Wasn't it supposed to collapse them all into one single call? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation doesn't say they get merged into a single call. Your queries get combined into a single *route*, and all queries are made simultaneously, but the mapping of query to network request is a concern of the network layer.

It is in fact the case that the default Relay network layer will issue a separate HTTP request for every query in a given route; this will happen regardless of whether you're using `react-router-relay` or whether you just happen to have a route with more than one query.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I believe there's an open feature request to have the network layer smart enough to aggregate the various queries, right?

Comment: I am not sure if there's a feature request for this, but it would be possible to build a custom network layer to do batching. (In fact, at Facebook our internal GraphQL endpoint has a batch endpoint that we can send a bunch of queries to in a single request, and get the results back in a single request.) Any implementation would be very backend-specific though, because the GraphQL spec doesn't currently impose any requirements about how queries should be transmitted.